# Strategy to make the website open for public via Route or User trigger

Tags: laravel

I have developed a Web App for a non profit entity. I am currently in staging mode. In-order for some routes to make accessible i have created a middleware.

Problem : The administration wants the Head of the Institution to make the website public. If so, what would be the best approach ?

My middleware

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{ 
    if(App::environment('local')) {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return new Response(view('layouts.coming-soon'));
    }
}

//routes
Route::middleware(['domain_block'])->domain('example.' . $tld)->group(function() {
   Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'showHomepage'])->name('homepage');
   Route::get('about-us',[PagesController::class, 'aboutUs'])->name('about_us');
});
```

I can understand if i store a value in a config via `Config::set('custom.my_val', 'mysinglelue');` , the request doesn't update from the config value until i clear the config cache.

Edit:
This plan is only to show people that it launched realtime and people can start using the web app. Later on i can remove the middleware.

When an user visits the webapp, the users sees all the routes except what is in the `domain_block` middleware. As this launching is going to happen while on a zoom meeting, people will expect to see the page right after the head of institution opens the page to the public. Users will reload the page to see the live page.

I am using Beanstalk for my deployment and it takes some time to build. That is why i wanted to go with a different approach so later on i could remove the middleware

Comment: You didn't explain your problem well, you just want the website to be accessible for public? if so, just remove implementing the middleware from routes.

Comment: @RatebHabbab, I will edit the question, Thank you for informing. I can remove the middleware from the backend. Since i am using Beanstalk with codedeploy, it will take some time to build. This opening to public approach is only to make the middleware routed routes to become public and people could see our WebApp. I will later on disable the middleware as we do not need it. so people can access without any objection.